# переход по всем нодам Views navigation

Tags: drupal, views

Здравствуйте, как сделать навигацию по всем нодам в Drupal 7 с помощью Views navigation... Ситуация: на главной блок который должен отображать 6 элементов, а их у меня к примеру 12, и этот модуль при переходе на ноду дальше 6-й не идет... как снять эту зависимость? Выводить это на отдельной странице вюшки не получится та как, на той странице отображаются все термины таксономии и + должна быть возможность перехода на конкретную страницу (ноду) при нажатии например 3-го блока сраху переход на 3-ю ноду...

Настройка количества вывода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отбражение на странице ноды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пагинация должна в блоке работать или нужен переход на 2ю странцу?

Comment: Переход на другую страницу, проблема в том, что этот модуль делает пути лишь к стольким нодам, сколько указано во вьюшке... можно было бы скрыть их, то будет их 80, а мне нужно только 6 последних, и лишний раз загружать не красиво...

Comment: возможно тогда выводить не блоком а странице будет проще, в таком случае? может быть я ошибаюсь. можете более подробно описать что есть и что хотите получить в итоге более подробно?

Comment: я внес изменения в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить параметр у "Use pager" c "Display a specified number of items" на "Paged output, mini pager" или "Paged output, full pager". Сейчас он у вас показывает только определенное количество элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках у параметра "Items to display" указать нужное вам количество элеметнов на странцу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь, но под рукой только русифицированный drupal.

Comment: У меня тоже, только мультиязичный)) Спасибо))